# Is it important to define a var when you can define in a function?

Tags: javascript, var

I have questions about defining a var in Javascript.
[Here is a JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ravaqi/1/edit?html,js,output)

```js
var newText=document.getElementById("myinput").value;

document.getElementById("changebutton").onclick=function(){
  newText=document.getElementById("myinput").value;
  document.getElementById("firstdiv").innerHTML=newText;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="myinput" type="text" value="test" />
  <button id="changebutton">Change!</button>
  <div id="firstdiv">This is some text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code, I want to show things next to the box where I can type things in. The code above works well, even without `var newText=document.getElementById("myinput").value;` in the first line of JS part.

So is it necessary to define variable? How would it be in some other cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you'd "dirty" your global scope as less as possible. In this case you'll call the variable exclusively inside an anonymous function, so the answer is: define it inside your function. You may quirkly not define the variable and most javascript engines will do it for you, but it's not a clear way to do it.

Golden rule: define a variable in an outer scope only if you need it in the outer scope or more than one "inner" scopes.

In this case you're dirting the outer scope without need.

Edit: in your case:

```
document.getElementById("changebutton").addEventListener('click',function(){
    var newText=document.getElementById("myinput").value;
    document.getElementById("firstdiv").innerHTML=newText;
});
```

Also note I've substituted `.onclick` with `addEventListener('click', function () {...` -> in this way you're able to bind multiple listeners for a single event.

Comment: Thanks Jack! So the inner function you meant is like the example without `var ...` line, or put `var...` line inside function(){}?

Comment: Ok! Thanks for suggestion. So `.addEventListener` is better since `.onclick` may be overwritten with two `.onclick` exist?

Comment: By a rule of thumb, `addEventListener` is highly suggested and yes, if you set `.onclick` twice or more, only the last function will be executed :) (differently than addEventListener)

Comment: Hi Jack, I got one more question... Would you please help me? D:
Is `var` needed inside the function(){} to define variable?

Comment: Hello Chenghua, you always have to define a variable via `var myVar[ = myValue]` before using it. If you haven't defined yet, you have to define it in the function.

In an environment where there are "global" (outer scope) variables, you don't have to define them again, otherwise the inner scope's variable will be different than the outer one and you won't be able to access the latter.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
document.getElementById("changebutton").onclick=function(){
  var newText=document.getElementById("myinput").value;
  document.getElementById("firstdiv").innerHTML=newText;
};
```